# handbreak duration for OMF files

Tags: transcode

When I preview an OMF video file in handbreak it plays in full though in low quality. However, the duration shown on the main screen shows a duration of 00:00:00 and when I try to export to mp4 it only exports a single frame. Has anyone else transcoded OMF video to MP4 successfully in linux?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which Linux distro exactly ? "Linux" is just the kernel, not greatly relevant here. Knowing the specific distro and whether you have codecs installed for the format is what matters. Keep in mind that the legendary VLC may reproduce a certain format well enough thanks to its own internal set of codecs and yet the required codec isn't available system-wide. In that case other software like **Handbrake** may not work with that format. From your description it seems it "sorta" works but not having the correct timestamp is a sign that something is missing. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: The specific issue is that handbreak is only transcoding one frame out of 12 seconds of footage. The distro is Fedora 39.